# NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.SessionFactory.openSession()

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm having hibernate3.jar and hibernate-core-4.2.0.CR1.jar in my classpath and I'm using Spring 3.1.3 version. Code got compiles sucessfully but while runtime I'm getting following error

> 2014-10-28 10:51:25,174 DEBUG [RMI TCP Connection(2)-10.126.30.203] -
>   Target method failed for RemoteInvocation: method name
>   'getPriceByKeys'; parameter types [java.util.List, java.util.Date] 
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.hibernate.SessionFactory.openSession()Lorg/hibernate/Session;

I google it but not find any solution. Please note : My project needs hibernate3.jar but at the same time my project dependent on some other 3rd party jar which inturn using hibernet4.2.0 jar.

Any help Pls ??

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove multiple hibernate JAR files from your `classpath`. Without doing this, your application may not work as you expect; which means you need to migrate the hibernate version of your application from 3 to 4.1.

Although Spring 3.1 uses Hibernate 3 JAR files, you can still migrate to Hibernate 4. Check out Spring blog gives a small tutorial to do so.

[Migrating to Spring 3.1 and Hibernate 4.1](https://spring.io/blog/2012/04/06/migrating-to-spring-3-1-and-hibernate-4-1)

> As part of the Core-Spring course, we have a lab application that we
>   use to show how to integrate Spring and JPA/Hibernate together. We
>   have just upgraded it to Spring 3.1 / Hibernate 4.1, and thought we
>   should share a few tips.

Answer (score 0):

Just an update. The cause of problem is , I'm having **two spring-context** xml files in project (one of my project and one related to another module that I'm integrating).  I'm loading context xmls from two different classes. So one of the **DAO** class loaded by one of spring-context xml not getting the **hibernate Session**.

Later on using import tag, I included 2nd spring application context file in 1st application context file and then loaded a Single application context file from the class. It solved the error.

Thanks,